# How can I use the billing address type field in another object

Tags: administration, configuration

I live the billing address field format, it is a great container for gathering all the fields together. Is there a way of doing this for customer objects?

Comment: Only the standard address fields on Account and Contact work this way. As far as I know, there is no way to create a new field with that data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been asked to do this many times, and can tell you the nice, rich functionality provided in the standard objects by Salesforce is *not currently* (June 2014/Spring 14/API 30) available to developers/users.

Here is an idea with 10k votes to make it available: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrVWAA0

Please throw your weight behind it!

Your only option really is to use multiple fields to gather the information and then a formula field to concatenate it and spend half a day fiddling with page layouts to get similar functionality.

(Ps. I really don't like SFSE answers that just say something is not possible... so I do hope someone can come along here with an awesome work around!)

Comment: ...still, this is where it is at the moment so I am obliged to accept it as an answer - I don't particularly need to have to code anything to handle the requirement.